# dropdownlistfor selected value with viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am not able to bind the selected value in MVC. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Members[i].OccupationCd,
   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddl_occupation"], 
   new { @style = "width:100px", @class = "Occupation required" })




 public List<SelectListItem> GetOccupation(string selectedValue)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selLstOccupation = new List<SelectListItem>();
        selLstOccupation.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "---" + ("Select Occupation") + "---" });
        selLstOccupation.AddRange(GetData.AllOccupation());
        selLstOccupation = GetData.GetSelectedList(selLstOccupation, selectedValue);
        return selLstOccupation;
    }

  public class Member()
  {
  //code
 //code   
   public int educationCd { get; set; }
  }
```

I found the Solution:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Members[i].OccupationCd,new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddl_occupation"],"Value","Text",Model.Members[i].OccupationCd))
```

Comment: Does nothing happen? Can you show me the code where you set the `ViewData["ddl_occupation"]`. Also you know that the first parameter is for the id you want to select.

Comment: No model used for loading dropdownlist. But the value to be selected is in model Called member above

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in you solution. `new SelectList(IEnumerable` should be `new SelectList((IEnumerable`

Comment: you are right . change done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things to fix your problem. The first one is to change the GetOccupation method with the following implementation

```
public List<Occupation> GetOccupation()
{
    return GetData.AllOccupation();
}
```

Then you have to change the dropdown initialization to the following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Members[i].OccupationCd,
   new SelectList(
       (IEnumerable<Occupation>)ViewData["ddl_occupation"], 
       "OccupationCd",
       "@@HERE YOU ADD THE PROPERTY YOU WANT TO VISUALIZE@@",
       Model.Members[i].OccupationCd),
   "---Select Occupation--",
   new { @style = "width:100px", @class = "Occupation required" })
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you please check this approach. I guess you will set the the ViewData["ddl_occupation"] = GetOccupations(). And one more thing don't forget to replace @@HERE YOU ADD THE PROPERTY YOU WANT TO VISUALIZE@@ with the actual value.

Comment: You are right. But there is no need to change the getoccupation implementation.See above.Anyway I mark it as correct .